# Improving a code to bring just folders that I choose

Tags: vba, file, directory

I have the code below that's working just fine. I got it from a site. In this code I choose the name of a file that I want to get and then It brings all the folders/subfolders where there's this file.
I want to refine with the name of the subfolders. I want to choose to return files that belongs in subfolders that contains the name "March" and "Week 2" for example.

```
Sub test()
  Dim MyDir As String, temp(), myList, myExtension As String
  Dim SearchSubFolders As Boolean, Rtn As Integer, msg As String
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show Then
      MyDir = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
  End With
  msg = "Enter File name and Extension" & vbLf & "following wild" & _
        " cards can be used" & vbLf & "* # ?"
  myExtension = Application.InputBox(msg)
  If (myExtension = "False") + (myExtension = "") Then Exit Sub
  Rtn = MsgBox("Include Sub Folders ?", vbYesNo)
  SearchSubFolders = Rtn = 6
  myList = SearchFiles(MyDir, myExtension, 0, temp(), SearchSubFolders)
  If Not IsError(myList) Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1).Resize(UBound(myList, 2), 2).Value = Application.Transpose(myList)
  Else
    MsgBox "No file found"
  End If
  Call DeleteRowNoInclude
End Sub

Private Function SearchFiles(MyDir As String _
                           , myFileName As String, n As Long, myList() _
                           , Optional SearchSub As Boolean = False) As Variant
  Dim fso As Object, myFolder As Object, myFile As Object
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each myFile In fso.GetFolder(MyDir).Files
    Select Case myFile.Attributes
      Case 2, 4, 6, 34
      Case Else
        If (Not myFile.Name Like "~$*") _
         * (myFile.Path & "\" & myFile.Name <> ThisWorkbook.FullName) _
         * (UCase(myFile.Name) Like UCase(myFileName)) Then
          n = n + 1
          ReDim Preserve myList(1 To 2, 1 To n)
          myList(1, n) = MyDir
          myList(2, n) = myFile.Name
        End If
    End Select
  Next
  If SearchSub Then
    For Each myFolder In fso.GetFolder(MyDir).subfolders
       SearchFiles = SearchFiles(myFolder.Path, myFileName, n, myList, SearchSub)
    Next        
  End If
  SearchFiles = IIf(n > 0, myList, CVErr(xlErrRef))
End Function
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable. What changes to your code have you tried so far?

Comment: Done! I'm learning haha

Comment: Well done! What changes to your code have you tried so far? Adding an `If` statement to the part where you add your results to the list to filter for your desired folder names should do the trick.

Comment: That's what I was trying, but Idk how to write this.. If (?).Name = "March"
Idk what string to put

Comment: After the line `ReDim Preserve myList(1 To 2, 1 To n)` add `Debug.Print(MyDir)` and `Debug.Print(myFile.Name)`. Look at the output in your immediate window. This way it should be easier to see on what to filter in your `If` statement.

Comment: I didn't see anything :(

Comment: Press ctrl+G to view the window